# C++ ambiguous overload for ‘operator ’

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

I'v read several posts here about this kind of errors, but I wasn't able to solve this one...
Has soon I define the operator int and the function f, fails to compile. 
I tested several things by I wasn't able to solve the issue....
Thanks

```
ex1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
ex1.cpp:35:13: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator+’ in ‘a + 4’
ex1.cpp:35:13: note: candidates are:
ex1.cpp:35:13: note: operator+(int, int) <built-in>
In file included from ex1.cpp:3:0:
Fraccao.h:41:9: note: Fraccao operator+(const Fraccao&, const Fraccao&)
ex1.cpp:38:13: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator+’ in ‘4 + a’
ex1.cpp:38:13: note: candidates are:
ex1.cpp:38:13: note: operator+(int, int) <built-in>
In file included from ex1.cpp:3:0:
Fraccao.h:41:9: note: Fraccao operator+(const Fraccao&, const Fraccao&)
```

The class:

```
class Fraccao {
    int numerador;
    int denominador;

public:
    Fraccao(int num = 0, int deno = 1) : numerador(num), denominador(deno) {}

    Fraccao & operator+=(const Fraccao &fra);

    Fraccao & operator*=(const Fraccao &fra);

    operator int() const;

    const Fraccao & operator++();
    const Fraccao operator++(int);

    string getAsString() const;
};

Fraccao operator +(const Fraccao &a, const Fraccao &b);
ostream & operator<<(ostream & saida, const Fraccao & fra);
```

And on my main:

```
void func(int n) {
    cout << n; // 
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //...
    d = a + b;
    const Fraccao h(7, 3);
    func(h);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where you declared the a?
d = a + b means what?
Put the variable declaration so we can sse what you are doing

Comment: That's the kind of things that happen when you have a class that is implicitly convertible both from _and_ to `int`...

Answer (score 18):

You don't seem to have posted the code that actually causes the error. I guess it looks something like

```
Fraccao a;
Fraccao b = a + 4;
Fraccao c = 4 + a;
```

The problem is that your class allows implicit conversions both to and from `int`; so `a + 4` could be either

```
int(a) + 4
```

or

```
a + Fraccao(4)
```

with no reason to choose one over the other. To resolve the ambiguity, you could either:

- make the conversion explicit, as above; or
- declare either the constructor or the conversion operator (or even both) `explicit` so that only one (or even neither) conversion can be done implicitly.

Comment: The explicit on the constructor with Daniel Frey's sugestion to make operators to receive (Fraccao, int) and vice-versa did the trick.
Thanx

Answer (score 14):

You have several options to fix your problem:

- Forbid implicit conversion from `int` to `Fraccao`: Make the constructor `explicit`.
- Forbid implicit conversion from `Fraccao` to `int`: Make the conversion operator `explicit`.
- Convert manually on the callers side, given `Fraccao f; int i;` either `int(f)+i` or `f+Fraccao(i)`.
- Provide additional overloads to resolve the ambiguity:

```
Fraccao operator +(const Fraccao &a, const Fraccao &b);
Fraccao operator +(const int a, const Fraccao &b);
Fraccao operator +(const Fraccao &a, const int b);
```

The latter probably means you also want:

```
Fraccao & operator+=(const Fraccao &fra);
Fraccao & operator+=(const int i);
```

And finally, if you want the latter, you can use libraries like [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) or my [df.operators](https://github.com/d-frey/operators/) to support you and avoid writing the same forwarders over and over again.

Answer (score 7):

The compiler sees two ways to interpret `a + 4`. It can convert the `4` to an object of type `Fraccao` and use `operator+(const Fraccao&, const Fraccao&)` or it can convert `a` to type `int` with the member conversion operator, and add `4` to the result. The rules for overloading make this ambiguous, and that's what the compiler is complaining about. In general, as @gx_ said in a comment, this problem comes up because there are conversions in both directions. If you mark the `operator int()` with `explicit` (C++11) the code will be okay.