# (No) Type casting while calling overloaded operators

Tags: c++11, casting, operator-overloading, c-strings

I am wondering whether there is an option to disable (?) type cast while initializing/comparing object to variables of specific type:

```
class X {
  //...
  const bool operator<=(const long long val) const;
  const bool operator<=(const char* val) const;
  const X& operator=(const long long val);
  const X& operator=(const char* val);
}

int main() {
  X x1 = 10;                //thats ok
  X x2 = "123";             //ok again
  X x3 = 0;                 //error, 0 is 'valid' char* 
  x1 <= 0 ? true : false;   //error, same reason
}
```

Here's the error: `more than one operator "<=" matches these operands`

Is there a way to get rid of these errors?
I know I can cast in `main` but unfortunately that's not what I want, or in fact  even allowed to do:

```
X x3 = (long long)0; //no no no...
```

Also - no `std::string`.

---

**Answer (partial)**
So the assignment part can be solved by changing class declaration - getting rid of `long long` assignment and making proper constructors explicit/implicit

```
// allow implicit conversion from long long, ex. X x = 13;
X(long long val)

// disable implicit conversion from const char*, now X x = 0 is ok - calls the above
explicit X(const char* val); 

// allow assignment from const char as well, no confusion with 0 now
const X& operator=(const char*);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819130/c-ambiguous-overload-for-operator

Comment: If you could get rid of the assignment operators and replace them with [explicit constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) you'll get rid of the errors. It's not possible to have the explict assignment though.

Comment: Thanks @RainingChain , @a-a I got the assignment running as you suggested but still `<=` operator is not properly set, do you have any other suggestions? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: Add an overload taking an `int`. `0` would prefer that over `char*`.

Comment: Is suffix an option? E.g. `X x3 = 0ll;`

Comment: I guess no. It is a task to write a class with given main function :) Probably should have mentioned it in the first place

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the call is ambiguous is that both overloads have the same standard conversion rank, according to table 12 under 13.3.3.1.1 [over.ics.scs] in the 14882:2011 ISO C++ standard. A `0` literal is of type `int`. A conversion to `long long` is an integral conversion (see 4.7), and a conversion to `const char*` is a pointer conversion (see 4.10).

The easiest solution is to just add overloads for `int`. You could simply call the `long long` version of the appropriate constructor/operator by casting the argument to `long long`, like so:

```
class X
{
public:
    // ...

    X(int i) : X((long long)i) { }
    const X& operator=(int i) { return operator=((long long)i); }
    // etc
};
```

Your partial solution "works", although the second line in `main()` in your example will then no longer compile. Because a conversion from `const char*` is made explicit, you are no longer allowed to do this:

```
X x = "Hi there!"; // error: no implicit conversion from const char[10] to X
X x("Hi there!");  // ok
```

Another caveat is that operations with a `long long` might be potentially expensive, depending on your implementation of X, because a temporary X needs to be constructed first before doing the assignment/comparison/etc.